# Random forest classification starting from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, random-forest

I have a lot of images of Earth and I need to find the section of the image where there is water using random forest.

I also have one JSON file (not GeoJSON) that have all the image's information. Inside the JSON file for each image there all the vertex points of the coordinates of the polygon (or polygons) that contains water in the image. The coordinates are related to the image and they are not geospatially referenced.

I have to train and test my network using random forest in order to find in a new image all the sections with water.

Do you have any suggestion how I can implement what I need in Python? 
Do you know any website/github code that I can use as reference?